# jMeter - How to get specific value from XML as String

Tags: xml, string, jmeter, request, response

I've this problem:
In my request I've to put a JSON as next:

```
{
    "key" : "value",
    "otherKey" : "${xmlFile}"
}
```

where ${xmlFile} is a String already created and formatted.
I make a request that as only response could be 'true' or get an error, so I never get an XML or JSON in the response.
What I need is to get the value of a specific tag in the xml -> pom:originalCodeVALUE</pom:originalCode>
In which way can I get the value?

- It's not important where in the script I can get the value.
- The xml file is stored in a folder and I get it to create the String using __FileToString() function.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [__XPath() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__XPath) allowing executing of [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) queries so you can extract a value from a specific tag using this function.

   Also if you're getting this file somewhere in the previous response instead of writing it to the file system you can just extract the necessary value using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter) and store it into a JMeter Variable
2. If the value contains special characters you might need to call [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson(java.lang.String)) method from [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T and thanks for your answer.
Unfortunally it's not working for me.
I've tried like this:
def xmlFile = ${__XPath(pathOfXmlStored, "//pom:PurchaseOrder</pom:originalCode")}
log.info("xmlFile: ${xmlFile}")
nut the JSR223 Sampler give to me:
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: xmlFile for class: Script238

Can you help me more please?

Comment: You shouldn't inline any JMeter Functions or Variables in Groovy scripts, you can put the __XPath() function directly into your request body. More information: [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). I also don't think your XPath expression is valid as it's missing [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xpath-queries-and-namespaces)

Comment: Unfotunally I'm not able as user of jMeter so I don't understan very well what is the problem.